# Bootstrap Accordion Collapse not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap but I can't get the accordion to collapse. It won't do anything. Any help? I have looked around and added the files needed but it still won't work. Any help would be appreciated. I'm using the latest Bootstrap files from the site.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

  <title>title</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.5/darkly/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="navbar-fixed-top.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
  <script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Fixed navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">title</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
              </li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="http://site.com.au">site.com.au</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container">

    <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h2><b>site</b></h2>
      <p>site</p>

      <div class="bs-example">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">1. What is HTML?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <p>HTML stands for HyperText Markup Language. HTML is the main markup language for describing the structure of Web pages. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">2. What is Bootstrap?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <p>Bootstrap is a powerful front-end framework for faster and easier web development. It is a collection of CSS and HTML conventions. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">3. What is CSS?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <p>CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheet. CSS allows you to specify various style properties for a given HTML element such as colors, backgrounds, fonts etc. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- /container -->


  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
  <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="site.com/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
  <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works perfectly [**JSFiddle link**](http://jsfiddle.net/zu8nnpgf/). This means that you might have problems with your scripts.

You have incorrect **bootstrap.js** CDN. Just change:

```
<script src="site.com/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

with this one:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

....

```
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">title</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="http://site.com.au">site.com.au</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">

    <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h2><b>site</b></h2>
        <p>site</p>

        <div class="bs-example">
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">1. What is HTML?</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <p>HTML stands for HyperText Markup Language. HTML is the main markup language for describing the structure of Web pages. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">2. What is Bootstrap?</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <p>Bootstrap is a powerful front-end framework for faster and easier web development. It is a collection of CSS and HTML conventions. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">3. What is CSS?</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <p>CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheet. CSS allows you to specify various style properties for a given HTML element such as colors, backgrounds, fonts etc. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be working fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/gzdtsnLd/

Have you linked to Bootstrap JS, CSS and jQuery on your web page? There could also be jQuery conflicts on your page preventing it from working?

```
<div class="bs-example">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">1. What is HTML?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <p>HTML stands for HyperText Markup Language. HTML is the main markup language for describing the structure of Web pages. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">2. What is Bootstrap?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <p>Bootstrap is a powerful front-end framework for faster and easier web development. It is a collection of CSS and HTML conventions. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">3. What is CSS?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <p>CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheet. CSS allows you to specify various style properties for a given HTML element such as colors, backgrounds, fonts etc. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```